# How can I delete ONLY my Stack Exchange Data Explorer profile?

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts

I would like to delete my profile on Stack Exchange Data Explorer but I want to keep all the profiles I got in other Stack Exchange sites.

How can I do that?

When I go to https://data.stackexchange.com/, click on "contact us" and  choose "I need to delete my user profile" the profile link is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/336030/carlatex and that's my Meta Stack Exchange Profile, not my SEDE profile.

I'd like to be sure that this is the correct way to delete ONLY my SEDE profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, not because it's all or nothing (Data Explorer accounts are not linked in any way to your network accounts) but because there's just no delete functionality on Data Explorer*.

I'll add it to the todo list.

<sub>*Just merge, but even that works Not Well™ sometimes</sub>

Comment: So, what's the status on that todo item?