# How can I delete my Stack Exchange Data Explorer account?

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

How can I delete an account on the [Stack Exchange data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

I can't find any way to request the deletion when logged in to the account.

(Note that SEDE is an independent system. SEDE accounts are not tied to Stack Exchange accounts. **This question is not about Stack Exchange accounts**.)

Comment: There is an admin path to delete an Openid: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/AdminController.cs#L249 just no self-service.

Comment: there is a trello card for it: https://trello.com/c/lpcaMFtF/13-ability-to-delete-users and a possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287954/how-can-i-delete-only-my-stack-exchange-data-explorer-profile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Tim Post's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325571/313042) is no longer up-to-date since I contacted support to have my SEDE profile deleted and received the following reply:

> Hello,
>
> We do not currently have any way of deleting profiles on Data Explorer. If you’d like to leave that site, we recommend simply changing your display name to something anonymous and then not logging in there again.
>
> Regards,
> Stack Overflow Team

Comment: Given that there's personal information on the account (the login credential), I'm pretty sure this is illegal in the EU.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It is extremely easy to just clear the three fields that actually contain any information and leave. We don't store anything extra from that site and I checked that Data Explorer accounts are excluded from GDPR requests altogether.

Comment: @animuson Is it? Last I tried you couldn't change the email address.

Comment: @animuson I had SEDE account with Google OpenId. I removed email from the SEDE account and now I can't login back. When I try the Google OpenID method then it creates a new account since it doesn't find the email address. How do I regain access to the SEDE account?

Comment: Support says that they can't help. At least delete my SEDE account if I can't regain access to it. Though regaining access would have been much better. This is the account in question: https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18244/rootkea